# How do I save BeautifulSoup web scraped table to csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I web scraped the contents of a table using this method and now I am looking to save it into a csv file but I am not sure how (it's for a project in class so I can't post any of my actual code because I might get flagged for plagiarism but I did exactly the same thing as the example).

I am new to data science/python so it might not have been the best method but it was the one I could figure out how to actually scrape the data.

https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-scrape-tables-with-beautifulsoup/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp").text)
# first we should find our table object:
table = soup.find('table', id="customers")
# then we can iterate through each row and extract either header or row values:
header = []
rows = []
for i, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
    if i == 0:
        header = [el.text.strip() for el in row.find_all('th')]
    else:
        rows.append([el.text.strip() for el in row.find_all('td')])

print(header)
['Company', 'Contact', 'Country']
for row in rows:
    print(row)
['Alfreds Futterkiste', 'Maria Anders', 'Germany']
['Centro comercial Moctezuma', 'Francisco Chang', 'Mexico']
['Ernst Handel', 'Roland Mendel', 'Austria']
['Island Trading', 'Helen Bennett', 'UK']
['Laughing Bacchus Winecellars', 'Yoshi Tannamuri', 'Canada']
['Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti', 'Giovanni Rovelli', 'Italy']
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest solution would be to use the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html).

You can [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) and then call [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to save it.

Using your example:

```py
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]  # [0] is the first table in the page

df.to_csv('table.csv', index=False)
```

Creates `table.csv`:

[image]

```
Company,Contact,Country
Alfreds Futterkiste,Maria Anders,Germany
Centro comercial Moctezuma,Francisco Chang,Mexico
Ernst Handel,Roland Mendel,Austria
Island Trading,Helen Bennett,UK
Laughing Bacchus Winecellars,Yoshi Tannamuri,Canada
Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti,Giovanni Rovelli,Italy
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a great built-in [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Here's the [the writer object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) which has a `writerow()` function that works with the input you have for it: a list of strings. Saving to a CSV file looks very close to the print statements you wrote, above.

E.g., add this to the end of your script, above. You can see that it first sets up a writeable file and then a csv writer object. Then, you use `writerow` in place of `print`, which you have.

```py
import csv
with open('contacts.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    contact_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    contact_writer.writerow(header)
    for row in rows:
        contact_writer.writerow(row)
```

`writer()` accepts a lot of options to help fine-tune the output.